# Emulate gestures in JavaScript using only code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ios, safari

I want to emulate a simple swipe-down gesture from one point to another using only JavaScript code or libraries.

[image]

I need the ability to control and change the main properties of the swipe, such as the starting and ending touch positions (x, y).

## I want to detect the gesture ?

No, i want to perform the gesture.

## Why do I want this?

Some events are triggered natively by the browser through gestures. In particular, I'm looking to automate a swipe gesture to hide the address bar in the Safari iOS browser.

For example, if I use a simple `scrollTo()` function to scroll the webpage, it will not trigger the event to hide the address bar.

This event seems to trigger only when I physically scroll down with my finger.